# How to clear a select when changed another (select2)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I have this two selects, where I only have to select one at a time:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Geo Blacklist</label>
        <select name="blacklist[]" multiple="multiple" id="blacklist"
            class="form-control select2"
            data-placeholder="Seleccionar uno o varios países" tabindex="1"
            onchange="$('#whitelist').val([]).change();">
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Geo Whitelist</label>
        <select name="whitelist[]" multiple="multiple" id="whitelist"
            class="form-control select2"
            data-placeholder="Seleccionar uno o varios países" tabindex="1"
            onchange="$('#blacklist').val([]).change();">
            <option>x</option>
            <option>y</option>
            <option>z</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I select anyone I get:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at RegExp.exec ()
> at [Symbol.replace] ()
> at String.replace ()
> at Function.camelCase (jquery.js:346:17)
> at Function.style (jquery.js:6643:22)
> at jquery.js:6866:12
> at jQuery.access (jquery.js:4142:5)
> at jQuery.fn.init.css (jquery.js:6849:10)
> at Search.resizeSearch (select2.full.js:2032:18)
> at DecoratedClass.resizeSearch (select2.full.js:580:32)

How can I do this?

Comment: I think your on change handlers are feeding off one another creating an infinite loop.

Comment: What you should do is not call on change of other drop down but set the other drop downs option

Comment: If not onchange, what event should I use?

Comment: Think about it from simple html javascript, you fire one event inside the function that executes you need to manipulate another element, which happens to be another select, so you need to find that element by id and set it's option to the blank, you DON'T need to fire that elements change handler

Comment: So steps are: 1 make selection 2 find the other select 3 set that selects option to 0 or or whatever you have for the default option, set the option to selected.

Comment: You might be able to use `.on('select2:select'` instead of `.on("change"` if you were using jquery events (and you should be) - then you wouldn't get the infinite loop.   If you still want `change` and/or still want inline events then the fix is to use `.trigger("change.select2")` - see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is with [select2](/questions/tagged/select2).   When changing a `<select>` value that's been select2-ised, you have to call `.change()` to update the UI.

This then triggers the 2nd `select` change event, which calls .change etc, creating an infinite loop as shown with `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

You can't simply remove the `.change()` as that would then not update the [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) UI.

The solution is described in the [select2 documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event)

> It's common for other components to be listening to the change event, or for custom event handlers to be attached that may have side effects [*such as an infinite loop*]. To limit the scope to only notify Select2 of the change, use the .select2 event namespace:

```
$('#mySelect2').val('US');
$('#mySelect2').trigger('change.select2'); // Notify only Select2 of changes
```

In the case of this question that would be to change

```
onchange="$('#blacklist').val([]).change();">
```

to

```
onchange="$('#blacklist').val([]).trigger('change.select2');">
```

(and the same for whitelist)

Here's a snippet (and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfcab4ne/)) that demonstrates `change.select2`.  Edit and change from `change.select2` to `change` and you get the infinite loop.

```js
$('.select2').select2();

$('#opt1').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
  $("#opt2").val([]).trigger("change.select2");
});
$('#opt2').on('change', function() {
  $("#opt1").val([]).trigger("change.select2");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2" id='opt1'>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>

<select class="select2" id='opt2'>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Maybe I am confused on the question, OP wanted to stop the infinite loop and clear out the other select. We stopped the infinite loop, but I still don't see your example clearing out the other select, I still see the value in the select when making selection on the opposite select.

Comment: @WPW ok.  My example snippet is showing that it's not creating an infinite loop, just set `.val([])` instead of `.val($(this).val())` - OP already had that part working.,  Updated snippet.   Removing `.change()` would not have the desired effect because OP is using [tag:select2].

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `.change()` as it trigger the change event on the other `select` and make infinite loop

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Geo Blacklist</label>
                <select name="blacklist[]" multiple="multiple" id="blacklist"
                    class="form-control select2"
                    data-placeholder="Seleccionar uno o varios países" tabindex="1"
                    onchange="$('#whitelist').val([]);">
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Geo Whitelist</label>
                <select name="whitelist[]" multiple="multiple" id="whitelist"
                    class="form-control select2"
                    data-placeholder="Seleccionar uno o varios países" tabindex="1"
                    onchange="$('#blacklist').val([]);">
                    <option>x</option>
                    <option>y</option>
                    <option>z</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't clear the other select

Comment: What do you mean by "clear the other select",  unselect the selected option or remove all options inside?

Comment: This works, it clears out the other select

Comment: I mean asign null to the value of the array and delete the selected options from the web

Comment: The issue is that OP is using [tag:select2] - and to update the UI you generally call .change() so without that, the UI is not being updated.  It works here, because this answer is not using select2.